# "this" keyword in JS

Tags: javascript, this

I'm trying to understand the "this" keyword in JS after having read a multitude of rather convoluted materials online. I am trying to come up with a simple rule to remember this topic. Please advise if the following is correct or complete. Thank you!

1. The "this" keyword in a function defined by the "function" keyword always refers to the calling object. The calling object might be the window object, an existing instance of a class, or a new object created via the "new" keyword. In the absence of a calling object, "this" reference to global.
2. In arrow functions, "this" refers to the immediate closing scope that contain the function.
3. In non-strict mode, "this" in a function is always undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at it from top to bottom scope:

Alone(global environment) and in a function that isn't called by an object, `this` always refers to the global object: `window`.

if in an function that is called by an object, `this` refers to to **that** object that called it. At example:

```js
const myObject = {
  firstName:"John",
  lastName: "Doe",
  fullName: function () {
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
  }
}
myObject.fullName();         // Will return "John Doe"
```

This also applies for a constructor function when being called with the `new` keyword(for instantiating objects in case you don't know yet), the difference is that it currently **does not** hold any value, because it will become a new object and `this` **then** holds the new object.

There are also a few exceptions to these to basic rules:

In an arrow function(ES6) the above object binding rules do not apply, in fact there is no binding at all directly inside it, and `this` is always the (inbuilt) object that defined the arrow function, that is, the `window` object.

Furthermore, when using 'strict mode', `this` is `undefined` within a function instead of the `window` object.

At last, There are the `call()`, `apply()` and `bind()` methods, is used to refer this to any object. Methods used for manipulating the `this` value in situations a developer wants to change and fixate the `this` value.

At example:

```js
const person = {
  fullName: function() {
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
  }
}
const person1 = {
  firstName:"John",
  lastName: "Doe"
}
const person2 = {
  firstName:"Mary",
  lastName: "Doe"
}

// This will return "John Doe":
person.fullName.call(person1);
```

or 'borrow' a method from another object:

```js
const person = {
  firstName:"John",
  lastName: "Doe",
  fullName: function () {
    return this.firstName + " " + this.lastName;
  }
}

const member = {
  firstName:"Hege",
  lastName: "Nilsen",
}

let fullName = person.fullName.bind(member);
```

The last two examples are maybe a bit tricky.

sources:

[function invocation](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_invocation.asp) [call()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_call.asp) [apply()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_apply.asp) [bind()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_bind.asp)

But that's it actually.

Comment: `this` is not always the `window` object inside an arrow function. `this` in an arrow function is determined by the `this` of the enclosing lexical scope of the arrow function.

Comment: You mean the case of a nested object?

Comment: I mean at all times. Consider all the usages of `() => this.setState({...})` as event handlers in react class components. Basically the definition of an arrow function closes over `this`. (I think I'm saying that right)

Comment: "With arrow functions the this keyword always represents the object that defined the arrow function."
--https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrow_function.asp